# UITapGestureRecognizer to cellForRowAt when button receive an event

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm a fresh start learner with Swift. I'm stuck here. I want when I tap the button, cell changes and show a warning but I think I'm wrong somewhere. Explain me, please. I consider a lot when I make a question.

Below is the code :

```
@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    ManagerProfileTableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "managerProfileCell") as! ManagerInformationTableCell
    let cellButton = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "buttonUpdateProfile") as! UpdateProfileTableCell

    if indexPath.row == titlesInformationArr.count - 1 {
        cellButton.updateButton.setTitle("Update", for: UIControlState.normal)
        cellButton.updateButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_: )))
        cellButton.updateButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cellButton.updateButton.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        if cell.informationTextField != nil {
            cell.warningImage.isHidden = true
        } else {
            cell.warningImage.isHidden = false
        }
        return cellButton

    } else {
        cell.informationTextField.text = titlesInformationArr[indexPath.row].value
        cell.titlesLabel.text = titlesInformationArr[indexPath.row].title
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: another simple way is that take one bool value like loadmanageProfileCell and assign true false value on tap and reload tableview and in cellForRowAt indexPath add one condition if  loadmanageProfileCell is true so load this cell or load another cell that's it. :) still any issue so let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cellButton` probably should not be a reusable cell - that's what `cell` is - but a UIButton that you add to the dequeued reusable cell. If you add it like this you have to think about the lifecycle of the cell. Because it is reusable you run the risk of adding a button to the cell even if it was previously used and already has a button... unless you are doing the inverse, and removing the button, with `prepareForReuse()`

(as you scroll up and down, when a cell goes off the screen it goes back into a pool of cells available for reuse and can be returned to you, in the state it was in when it disappeared, as you call `dequeueReusableCell`.)

In this case you are probably better off designing the prototype cell in interface builder and adding the button to it there, then subclassing UITableViewCell and making an IBAction in that subclass for the button event `touchUpInside`. When that action is received the cell can perform some action that might include calling a delegate method, where the view controller holding the table view is the delegate, to do something related to the table view like `reloadData()` in your example.

If you just want to detect a tap in the cell anywhere, a cell can already do that - just make sure the UITableViewDelegate is hooked up - commonly to the same place where you implement the UITableViewDataSource - and implement the method `func tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath)`. You should be able to find plenty of examples of using this method on this site.

If you want to know what the warning you see might mean can you edit the answer and include it?

Comment: I did it, thank you so much. I can't vote because my reputation is less than 15, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Lucifer You don't need to add UITapGestureRecognizer because UITableView has its own delegates you just need to attach tableview
by right clicking on tableview and drop it on ViewController

> See the Picture below

[image]

> Then call this delegate method in ViewController Class it will be called on Cell selection

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

// do what you want to do here 

}
```

Comment: I did it, thank you so much. I can't vote because my reputation is less than 15 :(. I'm so sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

you dont need a tapGesture on cell if you want to control cell From a Button.. you can simply add a tag to button then simply get that cell using tag. here is your amended code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "managerProfileCell") as! ManagerInformationTableCell
    let cellButton = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "buttonUpdateProfile") as! UpdateProfileTableCell

    if indexPath.row == titlesInformationArr.count - 1 {
        cellButton.updateButton.setTitle("Update", for: UIControlState.normal)
        cellButton.updateButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cellButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cellButton.addTarget(self , action : #selector(cellButtonTapped(_:)) , for : .touchUpInside)

        cellButton.updateButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        if cell.informationTextField != nil {
            cell.warningImage.isHidden = true
        } else {
            cell.warningImage.isHidden = false
        }
        return cellButton

    } else {
        cell.informationTextField.text = titlesInformationArr[indexPath.row].value
        cell.titlesLabel.text = titlesInformationArr[indexPath.row].title
        return cell
    }

@objC func cellButtonTapped(_ sender : UIButton){
  let index = sender.tag
  let cellToChange = tableView.cellForRowAt(indexPath : [0,index]) as! ManagerInformationTableViewCell
  cellToChange.backgroundColor = .green

}
```

Comment: I did it, thanks for your help. I can't vote because my reputation is less than 15 :(. I'm so sorry can't vote for you